# complex positioning elements (multiply rows)

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, element

all

tell me how to program elements so that when you change the screen size the one part of elements was positioned in several rows, and other - in a row

two cases:
https://s13.postimg.org/pswl5sfjr/example.png

html example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ehuoy97d/

```
<div class = "menu">
  <div class = "menu-border"></div>
  <div class = "menu-items-storage">
    <div class = "menu-item">#1</div>
    <div class = "menu-item">#2</div>
    <div class = "menu-item">#3</div>
    <div class = "menu-item">#4</div>
  </div>
  <div class = "menu-border"></div>
</div>

.menu {  
  width: 100%;

  background-color: #ffe0e0;

  font-size: 0px;
}

.menu .menu-border {
  display: inline-block;

  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;

  background: #bb0000;
}

.menu .menu-items-storage {
  display: inline-block; 
}

.menu .menu-item {
  display: inline-block;

  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

  margin: 0px 10px;
  padding: 0px;

  font-size: 16px;

  border: 2px solid #80ff80;
  background-color: #e0ffe0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, like this ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehuoy97d/1/)

```
.menu .menu-items-storage {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your issue, i think i got nearest to 90%..

check my fiddle : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ehuoy97d/8/)

I had to use play with `position` property.. sorry for not posting css as too much lines so.